# Undefine Symbols vtkImageViewer2::New(), QT-VTK Mac OSX 10.6.8

Tags: c++, macos, qt, vtk, itk

I'm using VTK to read a DICOM series. I can compile (using CMake) VTK example code and it runs well. Now, I'm trying to use Qtcreator and Qt4.8.5 to create a GUI. I have linked the library and include path on project.pro.

When I build, I get:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "vtkImageViewer2::New()", referenced from:
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New()        in mainwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

I checked, the Include path, and it includes /usr/local/vtk-6.1/include/vtk-6.1/
which contains vtkImageViewer2.h.

What's wrong with my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a linker error, so your project is indeed finding vtkImageViewer2.h correctly. You should use CMake to create your project, then you can simply do

```
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
```

and all of the VTK linking will be taken care of for you.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I'm going to compile it using cmake..
anyway, is there any solution so that I can use qt for compile the program?
I was following tutorial about "Displaying DICOM series" [HERE THE LINK](http://hxr99.blogspot.com/2013/03/qt-vtk-displaying-dicom-series-using.html)

is my vtk version could be the problem for linking?

Comment: CMake does not compile anything, it just creates a "project" (this could be Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc.). In your case, creating the default project, a "Unix" project, will create standard Make files that could be used to compile with 'make' from a terminal. Better than that, however, is that you can simply open the CMakeLists.txt file from QtCreator and it will create a QtCreator project for you. This is the process that I typically use in my work. To answer your question, I don't think it is a VTK version problem, but using CMake like this should definitely prevent that from being an issue.

Comment: thanks for sharing david it's very helpful, i use cmake for creating the project now

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to David's answer, do not forgot to add ${VTK_LIBRARIES} (defined by the VTK Use file) to your library or binary/executable:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myLib ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

and the paths to the libraries as:

```
link_directories(${VTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```